# How to implicitly define extended generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to infer T based on which `BasePage<T>` I am currently using. Trying to use `this.SetActivePage<T,U>()` is making me type T.

Is it syntactically impossible if so why?

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static void SetActivePage<T, U>(this PageBase<T> page) 
        where U : Page 
        where T : ViewModel
    {
        var mainWindow = page.Dependency.ServiceProvider.GetService<MainWindowViewModel>();
        mainWindow.ActivePage = $"../Pages/{typeof(U).Name}.xaml";
    }
}

public class PageBase<T> : Page where T : ViewModel
{
    public DependecyServiceProvider Dependency = DependecyServiceProvider.Instance;

    public T ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public PageBase()
    {
        ViewModel = Dependency.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a generic argument just to get its name? Why don't pass the type (or the name) as an argument to the method (`public static void SetActivePage<T>(this PageBase<T> page, string name)`)?

Comment: It _can_ infer `T`, but it _can't_ infer `U`. When it can't infer one or more of the generic arguments, it makes you type all of them.

Comment: Here is a good rule of thumb, if you have never seen the BLC do something, then most likely it cant be done or there is a good reason not to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I should expand my comment into an answer. The compiler *can* infer `T`, but it *can't* infer `U`. When it can't infer one or more of the generic arguments, it makes you type all of them. This is a design choice of the language, and I think the reasoning is so that in these situations it is easy for another programmer to read and understand which method is being called. This is particularly important if you have an overloaded method, where the overloads differ in the number of parameters and the number of generic arguments.

However, in the sample you have posted, you are declaring a generic parameter `U` for the sole purpose of getting the type through reflection. In this case, you could simply drop the parameter, and explicitly pass the type:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static void SetActivePage<T>(this PageBase<T> page, Type pageType) 
        where T : ViewModel
    {
        var mainWindow = page.Dependency.ServiceProvider.GetService<MainWindowViewModel>();
        mainWindow.ActivePage = $"../Pages/{pageType.Name}.xaml";
    }
}
```

This is a tradeoff - now instead of having to specify the generic parameters, you have to write `typeof()` when you call the method, but only for one parameter.

You also have the option of passing the name directly as a string, as per dcg's comment, which would probably be a better option.